# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No Such file or directory (Python)

Tags: python, json

I've downloaded and put `instances_train2017.json` file to the neccessary path. When I run my code I've seen this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 381, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 302, in main
    train_generator, validation_generator = create_generators(args)
  File "train.py", line 204, in create_generators
    **common_args
  File "C:\Users\mustafa\Desktop\EfficientDet-master\generators\coco.py", line 4
1, in __init__
    self.coco = COCO(os.path.join(data_dir, 'annotations', 'instances_' + set_na
me + '.json'))
  File "C:\Users\mustafa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycocotools\coco.py", line
85, in __init__
    dataset = json.load(open(annotation_file, 'r'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\mustafa\\Dow
nloads\\deneme.v1-1.coco\\train\\annotations\\instances_train2017.json'
```

Here is the directory of 'instances_train2017.json'

[image]

Why it doesn't see that file. Also I've tried to change relative path. But it is not possible.

here is the constructor in `coco.py`

```
def __init__(self, annotation_file=None):
        """
        Constructor of Microsoft COCO helper class for reading and visualizing annotations.
        :param annotation_file (str): location of annotation file
        :param image_folder (str): location to the folder that hosts images.
        :return:
        """
        # load dataset
        self.dataset,self.anns,self.cats,self.imgs = dict(),dict(),dict(),dict()
        self.imgToAnns, self.catToImgs = defaultdict(list), defaultdict(list)
        if not annotation_file == None:
            print('loading annotations into memory...')
            tic = time.time()
            dataset = json.load(open(annotation_file, 'r'))
            assert type(dataset)==dict, 'annotation file format {} not supported'.format(type(dataset))
            print('Done (t={:0.2f}s)'.format(time.time()- tic))
            self.dataset = dataset
            self.createIndex()
```

and constructor in generator/coco.py

```
def __init__(self, data_dir, set_name, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize a COCO data generator.

        Args
            data_dir: Path to where the COCO dataset is stored.
            set_name: Name of the set to parse.
        """
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.set_name = set_name
        if set_name in ['train2017', 'val2017']:
            self.coco = COCO(os.path.join(data_dir, 'annotations', 'instances_' + set_name + '.json'))
        else:
            self.coco = COCO(os.path.join(data_dir, 'annotations', 'image_info_' + set_name + '.json'))
        self.image_ids = self.coco.getImgIds()

        self.load_classes()

        super(CocoGenerator, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: The Windows file explorer typically doesn't show file extensions.  If the file is showing up as `instances_train2017.json1` in the Windows explorer, then I suspect the actual filename is `instances_train2017.json1.json`.

Comment: Can you open a command prompt in that directory and do a `DIR` command?